# How to format date from oracle database using hibernate

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, date, format

I know this is a very common question but i can't find any answer useful for me.
I'm working in a spring application using hibernate and getting data from an oracle database.
When i insert data into the database one of the fields is the current date that i format like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
```

And it works fine!

My problem is that when i want to print that date in a JSP it returns like this:

```
Fecha del mensaje: 2013-06-04 00:00:00
```

I want to display the date in this way: dd-MMM-YYYY but i just don't know how.
As i said before i'm working with spring and hibernate templates.

The code in my controllers is :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/detalle", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String detail(HttpServletRequest req, Map<String, Object> map){

        map.put("details", service.solPorId(req.getParameter("id_sol")));
        map.put("files", service.getFileId(req.getParameter("id_sol")));

        return "gestor/detalles";
    }
```

The method `service.solPorId("anyId")` just do a `select * from ... where id_sol=anyId`

And I'm calling the data in the JSP like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${details}" var="det">

<h2>Solicitud No. <c:out value="${det.id_sol}" /></h2>

<p>Alumno: <c:out value="${det.nombre}" /> <c:out value="${det.apellido}" /></p>
<p>Especialidad: <c:out value="${det.especialidad}" /></p>
<p>C&oacute;digo: <c:out value="${det.codigo}" /></p>
<p>Ciclo: <c:out value="${det.ciclo}" /></p>
<p>Asunto: <c:out value="${det.asunto}" /></p>
<p>Cuerpo del mensaje:</p>
<p><c:out value="${det.descripcion}" /></p>
<p>Fecha del mensaje:  <c:out value="${det.fecha}" /></p>
```

So anybody can help me in how to format that date ?
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

....

  <fmt:formatDate value="${det.fecha}" pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY" />
```

Comment: but that is JSF. I'm using JSTL, they can work together? I don't really know to much about that. Can you give me an example?. Thanks in Advance.